# Connection between Cloud Application and Local RPi

Tags: server

I have 2 servers, one is a cloud application and one is a local API used on a Raspberry PI to measure something that is only local.

I am searching for a secured way to send requests, from the cloud backend to the local raspberry API server (and to get the responses back in the user interface in cloud).
I've got as solutions until now only 'Weaved' application and the unsecured port forwarding.

Comment: You want to be reeeeeeeally careful about the word 'secured', particularly if there are any commercial aspects to your project. If you're serious about providing a secure service to users then this is likely not the best place to ask. You'll get better answers on securing an API on StackOverflow. What's your API implemented in, and do you have any platform requirements - Raspbian/Arch/Windows IoT...?

Comment: I am doing the local server in python or in node.js, I don't have problems in using any of those platforms, but I am trying to find a cheap solution for the MVP phase.
Thank you for your answer, I'll go ask on stackoverflow.